# Copy files into kubernetes pod with deployment.yaml

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have containerized microservice built with Java. This application uses the default `/config-volume` directory when it searches for property files.
Previously I manually deployed via `Dockerfile`, and now I'm looking to automate this process with *Kubernetes*.

The container image starts the microservice immediately so I need to add properties to the config-volume folder immediately. I accomplished this in Docker with this simple `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ########.amazon.ecr.url.us-north-1.amazonaws.com/company/image-name:1.0.0

RUN mkdir /config-volume
COPY path/to/my.properties /config-volume
```

I'm trying to replicate this type of behavior in a kubernetes `deployment.yaml` but I have found no way to do it.

I've tried performing a `kubectl cp` command immediately after applying the deployment and it sometimes works, but it can result in a race condition which cause the microservice to fail at startup.

(I've redacted unnecessary parts)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        image: ########.amazon.ecr.url.us-north-1.amazonaws.com/company/image-name:1.0.0
        name: my-service
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /config-volume
          name: config-volume
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          emptyDir: {}
status: {}
```

Is there a way to copy files into a volume inside the `deployment.yaml`?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was voted down. If there is something wrong with the question comment what you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to emulate a `ConfigMap` using volumes. Instead, put your configuration into a `ConfigMap`, and mount that to your deployments. The documentation is there:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/

Once you have your configuration as a `ConfigMap`, mount it using something like this:

```
...
  containers:
    - name: mycontainer
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /config-volume
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: nameOfConfigMap
```

Comment: I'll give this a try, but this isn't what I'm looking for. In this case I'm trying to upload a properties file but I want to be able to map any arbitrary file into a volume

Comment: Configmaps can be used to mount arbitrary files onto pods What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood what a ConfigMap is, this exactly what I needed.